# SQL Server BI: SIngle cube, multiple fact tables

Tags: sql-server, olap, business-intelligence, cubes

I'm new to creating cubes, so please be patient.

Here's an example of my data
I have multiple companies, each company has multiple stores.
Sales are each linked to a particular company, with a particular store on a particular date.
ex:5 sales took place for Company A, Store 1, on 5/19/2011
Returns are linked to a particular company on a particular date.
ex: 3 returns took place for Company A on 3/11/2012
Sometimes my users want to see a list of stores, the date, and how many returns took place, and how many sales.
Sometimes they want to see a list of companies, the specific stores, and the number of sales.

I have a table that stores 
COMPANY - DATE - STORE- SALES - RETURNS
I end up having the value for returns repeated for each store under a particular COMPANY - DATE pair.
so if I'm writing a query, and I want to find out returns, I just do a 
select distinct company, date, returns from mytable

but I am not sure how to this into a cube (using SS BI and Visual Studio).
(I've only made a couple of cubes so far)

Thanks! (also, feel free to point me at appropriate references)

Comment: I think your question would be a better fit over on [dba.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com/), you can consider self-flagging for migration there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like Company is an attribute of the Store and should be in the Store dimension rather than the fact table. There may have to be a transformation on returns to convert the Company to a store.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Oh, an interesting way of putting it!  We've decided to go another way for not (deadlines), but I'll keep that in mind for next time I get to try, thanks!